# Is it possible to register for PreShutdown service events using .Net?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I've run into a situation where I deployed a .Net (C#) service on a Win 2008R2 server.  The service has a dependency on MSMQ.  At shutdown it needs to send a couple of quick messages before terminating.  This works fine with manually triggered OnStop() events, but when the server is shutting down and the SCM calls OnShutdown() I'm finding that MSMQ has already shutdown and my service can't properly cleanup.  My service only needs 2-5 seconds to do it's work.

I understand (now) that service dependencies only apply to startup, so that isn't helping.  I spent some time today trying to figure out how to register my service to accept the newly (since Vista) available SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN events and work with the PreShutDownOrder feature (http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/02/04/ws2008-service-shutdown-and-crash-handling.aspx), but this isn't supported in the ServiceBase as implemented in the framework as far as I can tell.

I went down the path of trying to manually set it using the SetServiceStatus() function, but it doesn't appear to work.

```cs
_serviceHandle = this.ServiceHandle;
SERVICE_STATUS serviceStatus = new SERVICE_STATUS();
serviceStatus.currentState = (int)State.SERVICE_RUNNING;
serviceStatus.controlsAccepted = (int)(ControlsAccepted.SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN | ControlsAccepted.SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP);
serviceStatus.waitHint = 0;
serviceStatus.checkPoint = 0;
bool setStatus = SetServiceStatus(_serviceHandle, ref serviceStatus);
int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

This returns an error status of 13 when you call `GetLastError();`

Any ideas for how to hook into the preshutdown service events?

Comment: Error 13 is "The data is invalid". Are you sure you've filled in the SERVICE_STATUS structure properly?

Comment: Just as a followup, it is possible.  I was able to make this work by creating my own ServiceBase from a decompiled copy of ServiceBase and adding the required handlers for preshutdown.

Comment: I am looking for a C example to subscribe to pre-shutdown can someone help please. My question got downvoted so I deleted it just now

Answer (score 2):

OK then the other alternative is to create/get/buy a C++ service that registers for the PreShutdown stuff and stops/shuts down your .Net services in your required order (and waits for them to actually exit).

It could either have its own shutdown order list/graph or build it using the existing Windows start up dependencies (ignoring services that it should not manage).

Answer (score 0):

If you  will write a message to the database/file when the service will close and than when
the computer up again, check the table/file and send message to MSMQ

Comment: There are workarounds, but this answer doesn't really address the question.  The messages that need to be sent are critical to orderly shutdown of other processes, so saving the data and trying later is not an option.

Comment: I did not find anything. I think you cannot set the order of shutdown services and you cannot subscribe to close of msmq.

Comment: I agree that I can't influence MSMQ's shutdown, but maybe I can get mine notified of the shutdown first.  If you look at the article that I linked to in the question, you will see that it is indeed possible (since Vista).  The question is, how do you hook into this functionality from a .Net service.

Comment: Antoher workaround , you can check msmq from another service every 5 second if it's live , if it's not to send message to your service

Comment: Another solution is to subscribe to  to get updates to the "System" Event Log. When MSMQ is shutting down , may be it will write to Event Log. When the computer is shutting down "The Event log service was stopped." will appear and than maybe message can be sent to MSMQ